# Pandas : replacement of specific n-th characters

Tags: python, replace, pandas

I'm beginner and learning python.
Although I'm familiar with SAS, Python language is different with SAS's.
So, I've been learning python language step by step by searching syntax and others.

I want to know how to replace sub-string with pandas, like 'SUBSTR' in SAS.

Specifically, I want to convert `YYYYMM`(year-month form) into `YYYYQ`(year-quarter form). i.e

```
201102 --> 20111  
201106 --> 20112  
201110 --> 20114
```

To do this, I should substitute 1 character for every 5~6th 2 characters.

By searching this subject, I've known basic syntax of replace(). But I couldn't apply to my specific problem.

I attach code sample below.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = DataFrame({'date' : ['201101','201102','201103','201104','201105','201106']},
                 index = ['1','2','3','4','5','6'])
df['new_date'] = df['date'].str.replace('01','1')
print(df)
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example that clarifies what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry. Because this is my first question, I couldn't write carefully. On comment from your reply I edited my question. Your answer during that time is thankful and helpful.

Comment: No worries, I think providing sample code, as you did is the way to go on StackOverflow, so keep doing this in the future :). And welcome to StackOverflow and Python.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should treat the dates as proper dates, not strings. Take a look at pandas' [time series functionality](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html).

To interpret your example of YYYYMM strings as dates, use the format string `%Y%m`:

```
In [21]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m')

In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
        date
1 2011-01-01
2 2011-02-01
3 2011-03-01
4 2011-04-01
5 2011-05-01
6 2011-06-01

[6 rows x 1 columns]
```

Then use the rollback functionality to get the quarter start date from each date. There are many different "offsets" available. I don't think this is the one you want, but this illustrates the process. Take a look at the docs for more.

```
In [23]: from pandas.tseries.offsets import BQuarterBegin

In [24]: offset = BQuarterBegin()

In [25]: df['date'].apply(offset.rollback)
Out[25]: 
1   2010-12-01
2   2010-12-01
3   2011-03-01
4   2011-03-01
5   2011-03-01
6   2011-06-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```